# How to expand a composite function into series?

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

I need to expand such a function 
$$g[y,z(x,y)]=\frac{-y (z+1)^4-z^4-4 z^3+8 z+8}{z+1},\tag{1}$$ into powers of $x$ and $y$. Among $x,y,z$ there is a constraint equation, for example 
$$(3 y+3) z^4+z^3 (4-8 x+12 y)+z^2 (18 y-24 x)+z (12 y-24 x)-8 x+3 y=0.\tag{2}$$
There is also the requirement, $z\rightarrow 0$ as $x,y \rightarrow 0$.

The most direct method is to solve Eq.(2) for $z$, and then substituting the $z=z(x,y)$ into Eq.(1) to obtain $f(x,y)$. At last, one can use, such as

```
Series[f[x,y],{x,0,2},{y,0,1}]
```

to expand the composite function as a series of $x$ and $y$.

The code for the two equations are:

```
g[y_,z_]:=(8 + 8 z - 4 z^3 - z^4 - y (1 + z)^4)/(1 + z);
```

and

```
-8 x + 3 y + (-24 x + 12 y) z + (-24 x + 18 y) z^2 + (4 - 8 x + 
 12 y) z^3 + (3 + 3 y) z^4 == 0;
```

I tried this direct method. It takes a very long time, but I do not get a result. If the constraint equation is not only a quartic equation, but a more complicated algebraic equation, the direct method may not work. I want to know whether there are simpler methods to deal with this kind of problems?

**Additional remarks**：

According to @Daniel Lichtblau's method, one can first expand the implicit function equation (the constraint equation) into a series of $x,y$. The key problem here is that we cannot first expand $z=z(x,y)$ formally as a standard Taylor series, and then substitute it into the constraint equation to solve the coefficients, because the true series of  $z=z(x,y)$ may have minus power, even fractional power of $x$ or $y$. Below is an example: a simple quadratic equation,

```
-x + y + (4 x + y) z - (3 + 2 y) z^2==0
```

We certainly can solve it to obtain
$$ z=\frac{\sqrt{16 x^2-12 x+9 y^2+12 y}-4 x-y}{2 (-2 y-3)}. $$ (* the first root *)
Expanding the solution, 
`Series[z, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]`,
one can obtain such a result
$$ \left(-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{y}{6}+O\left(y^{3/2}\right)\right)+x \left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{y}}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{25 \sqrt{y}}{48 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{4 y}{9}+O\left(y^{3/2}\right)\right)+x^2 \left(\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{3} y^{3/2}}-\frac{19 \sqrt{3}}{64 \sqrt{y}}+\frac{333 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{y}}{1024}+O\left(y^{3/2}\right)\right)+O\left(x^3\right).$$

I also tried the methods on this post: [Calculating Taylor polynomial of an implicit function given by an equation][1]
  [1]: [Calculating Taylor polynomial of an implicit function given by an equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/calculating-taylor-polynomial-of-an-implicit-function-given-by-an-equation/116322#116322), it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to scale `x` and `y` and to then find the series in terms of the scaling parameter. For instance:

```
constraint = -8 x + 3 y + (-24 x + 12 y) z + (-24 x + 18 y) z^2 + (4 - 8 x + 12 y) z^3 + (3 + 3 y) z^4 == 0;
roots = Solve[constraint /. {x -> s x, y -> s y}, z, Quartics->False]
```

> {{z -> Root[-8 s x + 
>         3 s y + (-24 s x + 12 s y) #1 + (-24 s x + 18 s y) #1^2 + (4 - 8 s x + 
>            12 s y) #1^3 + (3 + 3 s y) #1^4 &, 1]}, {z -> 
>      Root[-8 s x + 
>         3 s y + (-24 s x + 12 s y) #1 + (-24 s x + 18 s y) #1^2 + (4 - 8 s x + 
>            12 s y) #1^3 + (3 + 3 s y) #1^4 &, 2]}, {z -> 
>      Root[-8 s x + 
>         3 s y + (-24 s x + 12 s y) #1 + (-24 s x + 18 s y) #1^2 + (4 - 8 s x + 
>            12 s y) #1^3 + (3 + 3 s y) #1^4 &, 3]}, {z -> 
>      Root[-8 s x + 
>         3 s y + (-24 s x + 12 s y) #1 + (-24 s x + 18 s y) #1^2 + (4 - 8 s x + 
>            12 s y) #1^3 + (3 + 3 s y) #1^4 &, 4]}}

*(I used the [`Quartics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quartics)->[`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) option because [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) works much better with [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects)*

The first root is the branch where `z == -4/3`:

```
roots[[1]] /. s->0
```

> {z -> -(4/3)}

So, you are interested in the other 3 roots:

```
roots[[2 ;; 4]] /. s->0
```

> {{z -> 0}, {z -> 0}, {z -> 0}}

Mathematica can find the series expansion of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects. For example:

```
zser = Series[z /. roots[[2]], {s, 0, 1}];
zser //TeXForm
```

> Root::sbr: Because of branch cuts, the series may represent a different root of -8 s x+3 s y+(-24 s x+12 s y) #1+(-24 s x+18 s y) #1^2+(4-8 s x+12 s y) #1^3+(3+3 s y) #1^4& for some values of {x,y,s}.
>
> $\frac{\sqrt[3]{s} \sqrt[3]{8 x-3 y}}{2^{2/3}}+\frac{s^{2/3} (24 x-13 y)}{8 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{8 x-3
>    y}}+\frac{1}{64} s (56 x-57 y)+O\left(s^{4/3}\right)$

Plugging this into your `g` expression:

```
(8 + 8 z - 4 z^3 - z^4 - y (1 + z)^4)/(1 + z) /. {x -> s x, y -> s y, z -> zser} //Simplify //TeXForm
```

> $8+s (2 y-8 x)+O\left(s^{4/3}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same approach as in [this recent MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192509/multivariate-series-for-approximating-implicit-system/192848?noredirect=1#comment502178_192848).

The derivatives can be found iteratively using the constraint.

The set-up:

```
g[y_, z_] := (8 + 8 z - 4 z^3 - z^4 - y (1 + z)^4)/(1 + z);
poly[x_, y_, z_] := -8 x + 
   3 y + (-24 x + 12 y) z + (-24 x + 18 y) z^2 + (4 - 8 x + 
      12 y) z^3 + (3 + 3 y) z^4;
zconstraint = poly[x, y, z[x, y]];
```

First solve for `z` at `x=0,y=0`. We use the constraint only (and similar when solving for derivatives).

```
zsolns = 
 Solve[(zconstraint /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}) == 0, z[0, 0]]

(* Out[659]= {{z[0, 0] -> -(4/3)}, {z[0, 0] -> 0}, {z[0, 0] -> 
   0}, {z[0, 0] -> 0}} *)
```

We'll work with the branch hitting -4/3.

```
zderivsolns = 
 Solve[{D[zconstraint, x] == 0, 
     D[zconstraint, y] == 0}, {D[z[x, y], x], D[z[x, y], y]}] /. {x ->
      0, y -> 0} /. zsolns[[1]]

(* Out[660]= {{Derivative[1, 0][z][0, 0] -> 1/24, 
  Derivative[0, 1][z][0, 0] -> 1/192}} *)
```

Iterate to get the higher order derivatives needed for the series.

```
zderiv2solns = 
 Solve[{D[zconstraint, {x, 2}] == 0, 
      D[zconstraint, {x, 1}, {y, 1}] == 0, 
      D[zconstraint, {x, 2}, {y, 1}] == 0}, {D[z[x, y], {x, 2}], 
      D[z[x, y], {x, 1}, {y, 1}], 
      D[z[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 1}]}] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0} /. 
   zsolns[[1]] /. zderivsolns

(* Out[686]= {{{Derivative[2, 0][z][0, 0] -> -(3/128), 
   Derivative[1, 1][z][0, 0] -> 
         -(11/3072), Derivative[2, 1][z][0, 0] -> 135/32768}}} *)
```

Now take a series for `g`, convert to a Taylor polynomial, and plug in values for `z` and the needed partial derivatives.

```
ser = Normal[Series[g[y, z[x, y]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]];
ser /. zsolns[[1]] /. zderivsolns /. zderivsolns /. zderiv2solns

(* Out[695]= {{{{-(296/27) + x^2 (1/9 - (13 y)/1152) + 
     x (-(8/9) + y/36) - (2 y)/27}}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why do you " work with the branch hitting -4/3". In fact, in my problem there is the requirement, z->0 as x,y ->0. I have added this requirement in my question.  If so, how can  I expand the function?

Comment: I chose that one because it was simple and because I failed to notice that requirement in the post. Try it using the one where `z` goes to zero. Might work fine, if the multiplicity of the root does not cause trouble.

Comment: Disregard, I see your point. It is a Puiseux series at `z=0`.